# Add attribute when new node create in JSTree

Tags: jquery, jstree

How to add attribute when creating new node in JStree?

When btnadd click that time i am adding new node.
node is created successful but now i want to add attribute.

My Html

```
<div id="jstree">
</div>

<button id="btnadd">create node</button>

<div id="CurentNodeName"></div>
<div id="CurentNodeId"></div>
```

Script

```
<script>
    var CurrentNode;
    $(function () {
        var data = [
           { "id": "ajson1", "parent": "#", "text": "Simple root node" },
           { "id": "ajson2", "parent": "#", "text": "Root node 2" },
           { "id": "ajson3", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 1" },
           { "id": "ajson4", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 2" },
        ];
        $("#jstree").jstree({
            "core": {
                // so that create works
                "check_callback": true,

                "data": data
            } 
        }).on('create_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
            console.log('saved');
        });

        // listen for event
        $('#jstree').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
            var i, j, r = [], s = [];
            for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
                r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text);
                CurrentNode = data.selected[0];
                console.log(data.selected[0]);

            }

            $('#CurentNodeName').html('Selected: ' + r.join(', '));
            $('#CurentNodeId').html('Selected Id: ' + CurrentNode);

        }).jstree();

        // create the New Node when Button Click
        $("#btnadd").on("click", function () {

            $('#jstree').jstree().create_node(CurrentNode, { "id": "ajson5" + CurrentNode, "text": "newly added" }, "last", function () {                   
           });   
    });

</script>
```

i also try 
"attr": { title:"if",value:"expression"} } but that not help me.

Comment: Try `data[i].attr = { title: "if", value:"expression"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way. its work for me

```
$('#jstree').jstree().create_node(CurrentNode, { 
    li_attr: { "path": "path" },"text": "name" }, 
    "last", function () { }, true);
```

Comment: CurrentNode is my current node so please take care of this